# Javascript to render kbd tagged elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to write a (Javascript?) function to be included in HTML pages that allows me to render the function arguments tagged as `kbd` separated by "+"s and able to take an arbitrary number of input arguments.

So, for example, `fnRenderKBD(Ctrl+X, Y, Z)` would render as <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

The important thing is that the function should be able to take a variable number of arguments.

Is it possible to write such a function (if so, how)? I have next to no knowledge of JS.

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to get the HTML working correctly with some test cases. When you have done that, come back with what you have and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer at the bottom is not the best thing I have ever written. A better solution would look something like:

```
function fnRenderKBD(elem, keysToDisplay) {
    var delimiter = '';
    var content = null;
    for(var i = 0, length = keysToDisplay.length; i < length; i++) {
        var renderedKey = document.createElement('kbd');
        renderedKey = setText(renderedKey, keysToDisplay[i]);

        if (i > 0) {
            elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('+'));
        }

        elem.appendChild(renderedKey);
    }
}

function setText(elem, text) {
   if (elem.textContent){
      elem.textContent = text;
   }else{
      elem.innerText = text;
   }

   return elem;
}

(function() {
    var keys = [
        'Ctrl+X',
        'Y',
        'Z'
    ];

    var elem = document.getElementById('display');

    fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
}());​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wPg7z/

---

Something like this should work:

```
function fnRenderKBD(elem, keysToDisplay)
{
    var delimiter = '';
    var content = '';
    for(var i = 0, length = keysToDisplay.length; i < length; i++) {
        content+= delimiter + '<kbd>' + keysToDisplay[i] + '</kbd>';
        delimiter = '+';
    }

    elem.innerHTML = content;
}

(function() {
    var keys = [
        'Ctrl+X',
        'Y',
        'Z'
    ];

    var elem = document.getElementById('display');

    fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
})();
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gTYxP/1/