# Linking CSS, Javascript and HTML process fail

Tags: javascript, html, css

So using the advice I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135449/1414455), I tried to implement it like this:

1. I created the following `kbd.js` file:

   ```js
   function fnRenderKBD(elem, keysToDisplay)
   {
       var delimiter = '';
       var content = '';
       for(var i = 0, length = keysToDisplay.length; i < length; i++) {
           content+= delimiter + '<kbd>' + keysToDisplay[i] + '</kbd>';
           delimiter = '+';
       }
       elem.innerHTML = content;
   }
   (function() {
           var keys = [ 'Ctrl+X','Y','Z'];   
           var elem = document.getElementById('display');
           fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
       }
   )();
   ```
2. Then I created the following stylesheet, called `kbd.css`:

   ```css
   kbd {
       padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
       border: 1px solid #CCC;
       font-size: 11px;
       font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
       background-color: #F7F7F7;
       color: #333;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 0 0 2px #ffffff inset;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 0 0 2px white inset;
       box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0 0 0 2px white inset;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       border-radius: 3px;
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0 0.1em;
       text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
       line-height: 1.4;
       white-space: nowrap;
   }​
   ```
3. Then, I tried to construct a simple HTML file to check the results, called `keyboard-rendering.htm`

   ```
   <script src="kbd.js"> </script>
   <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="kbd.css" TYPE="text/css">​
   <div id="display"></div>​
   ```

My question is, why does this not work (output is "â€‹"), that is, why does it not give me the same output as the lower right quadrant [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gTYxP/1/).

Comment: you have typos in your code (as highlighted) - unclosed string literals

Comment: Right, so I have made the changes from your edit, however, I still get the same output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe follow this:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var keys = [ 'Ctrl+X','Y','Z'];   
    var elem = document.getElementById('display');

    fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
};
```

and check your page's charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: Ok, so I am pretty sure that there are non-ASCII characters hiding in my HTML document somewhere, but I can't find them.
I added the meta line you suggested to the top of my HTML file, but I still get the "â€‹" character. How can I remove this?

Comment: So let's change '<kbd>' in '<span>' in js function just for try. Have you still the same problem? At last try changing 'elem.innerHTML' in 'elem.outerHTML'. 'outerHTML' sets the source code including the opening and closing tags of the element without formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both the things you suggested: 1) Changed the tags from `kbd` to `span`, and; 2) changed `innerHTML` to `outerHTML`. I still get the weird output...

Comment: Do you get "â€‹" in place of kbd or inside?

Comment: I get the correct output, surrounded by the characters:
â€‹
Ctrl+X+Y+Z
â€‹

Comment: First of all try this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`... anything change? I have other ideas.

Comment: If not change it `elem.innerHTML = content;` in js function with `elem.innerHTML = unescape(content);` and try with both charset.

Answer (score 1):

Call your script at the end of the page. because your script not finding element with id "display".

Change this

```
<script src="kbd.js"> </script>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="kbd.css" TYPE="text/css">​
<div id="display"></div>​
```

to

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="kbd.css" TYPE="text/css">​
<div id="display"></div>​
<script src="kbd.js"> </script>
```

or, if you want to include your script file first than change function in kbd.js

```
(function() {
        var keys = [ 'Ctrl+X','Y','Z'];   
        var elem = document.getElementById('display');
        fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
    }
)();
```

to

```
window.onload = function() {
    var keys = [ 'Ctrl+X','Y','Z'];   
    var elem = document.getElementById('display');
    fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your most-immediate error is that `'display'` is put on the page ***after*** the .js file is loaded.

When a browser downloads a .js file, it runs the contents inside ***AS SOON AS THE DOWNLOAD IS FINISHED***.

That means that when your keyboard code is loaded, it's setting up before the `<div>` even exists.

That would be fine, if you were setting up functions that you could fire later on.
But the code at the bottom of the .js file, the stuff inside of the `(function () {}());` is set to fire right away.  It's looking for `<div>` and it's not going to find it.

Move the .js file to be below everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your script at the end of your page and then it will work properly

***LINK JS***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="kbd.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bring your js include in the bottom.

```
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="kbd.css" TYPE="text/css">
<div id="display"></div>
<script src="kbd.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put your script code in the body tag after div element, like this:

```
<body>

<div id="display"></div>
<script>
function fnRenderKBD(elem, keysToDisplay)
{
    var delimiter = '';
    var content = '';
    for(var i = 0, length = keysToDisplay.length; i < length; i++) {
        content+= delimiter + '<kbd>' + keysToDisplay[i] + '</kbd>';
        delimiter = '+';
    }

    elem.innerHTML = content;
}

(function() {
    var keys = [
        'Ctrl+X',
        'Y',
        'Z'
    ];

    var elem = document.getElementById("display");
    fnRenderKBD(elem, keys);
})();
</script>

</body>
```

it will work :)